# Unir dos consultas similares de una misma tabla

Tags: mysql

hace horas estoy con este problema que supongo que podrá ser solucionado pero no he hallado aún la solución por eso llegué aquí:

PROBLEMA: Tengo dos tablas evaluadores y cargo, en la tabla de evaluadores hay dos campos que necesito `idCargo` y `IdCargoEvaluado`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ese `idCargo` y `IdCargoEvaluado` viene de la tabla "cargo" donde se muestra el nombre del cargo según su id:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo esta consulta:

```
select eval.id, eval.idCargo, car.nombre, eval.idCargoEvaluado from 
evaluadores eval, cargo car where eval.idCargo = car.id order by id asc
```

Pero solamente me muestra el nombre de `idCargo` necesito que también se muestre el nombre de `idCargoEvaluado` que también viene de la tabla "Cargo".

Espero haya explicado bien.

Answer (score 0):

Según se puede ver, en la tabla `evaluadores` tienes **dos llaves foráneas** a la tabla `cargo`. Entonces, si para cada una de ellas quieres saber el cargo tienes que hacer un doble `JOIN`, o sea, uno por cada llave foránea.

Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT
    e.id, 
    e.idCargo, 
    c1.nombre cargo1, 
    c2.nombre cargo2, 
    e.idCargoEvaluado 
FROM evaluadores e
    INNER JOIN cargo c1 ON e.idCargo = c1.id
    INNER JOIN cargo c2 ON e.idCargoEvaluado = c2.id
ORDER BY e.id ASC
```

He usado alias más cortos por motivos de simplicidad.

Notarás que se implica la tabla `cargo` dos veces en el `JOIN`, dándole los alias `c1` y `c2`. Luego en el `SELECT` para obtener el nombre del cargo en cada caso, notarás que se usa `c1.nombre` para la coincidencia que corresponde a `idCargo` y `c2.nombre` para la coincidencia que corresponde a `idCargoEvaluado`.